# Windows Server 2012 apache not starting

Tags: apache-2.2, windows-server-2012-r2

I'm having difficulty getting apache to run. I is giving me the following error

```
The request operation has failed
```

I have disables IIS from the services but when I go to 127.0.0.1 on the browser I can see the Windows Server 2012 Remote Web Access screen.

How can I disable this so that I can run Apache?

*UPDATE*

I get this error when I try to start Apache using the Apache Start shortcut

```
An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions : make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
```

Comment: Is remote desktop services role installed with web access ?

Comment: I didn't install it it's just there, must be default with the OS installation

Comment: It's not there by default, you should remove it if you're not using it.

Comment: I'm trying to remove it I don't know how though

Comment: Server Manager - Manage - Remove Roles and Features

Answer (score 1):

I have been struggling with this issue since last 2 hours :(

It was common issue of 80 being used by another services. Normally stopping the `IIS` would be fine but here it wasn't working for me.

There are other solution suggested over the web/SO to use `net stop http` but that would stop some other services that might be required for normal system functioning.
Like the `net stop http` command give following error

```
The following services are dependent on the HTTP Service service.
Stopping the HTTP Service service will also stop these services.

   Windows Remote Management (WS-Management)
   Print Spooler

Do you want to continue this operation? (Y/N) [N]:
```

**What worked for me:**

While scrolling through the list of services i have found one item that I suspected would be interfering. I've stopped the service and the apache was working now.

Not sure, if this is good solutions for long term but it works fine for me.

Comment: Since this issue I've had multiple other issues with similar Services Conflicting with each other. I've gone back to using IIS primarily on Windows just because it seems more Windows friendly